# Classification Problems in Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

My field of interest is Lie group analysis of PDEs, currently I am struggling with techniques for classification of Lie algebra into mutually conjugate classes of 1- and 2-dimensional sub-algebras through adjoint action.

1. I have studied technique of [Peter Olver](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=sI2bAxgLMXYC&redir_esc=y) (chapter 3, example 3.12) where successive adjoint action on general element in Lie algebra leads to optimal classification of Lie algebra.
2. The second technique is by given [Patera and co-authors](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/16/8/10.1063/1.522729) through abstract Lie algebra.

I believe that the later technique is far superior to that of Olver, but as I am being not much familiar with abstract Lie algebra, so I don't know how should I proceed for classification of Lie algebra using technique given by Patera and co-authors.
As an example I list Lie algebra for well known KdV equation as follow:

$V_{1}=\partial_{t}, V_{2}=\partial_{x}, V_{3}=x\,\partial_{x}+2t\,\partial_{t}, V_{4}=u\,\partial_{u}, V_{5}=\,2t\,\partial_{x}-xu\,\partial_{u}$,
$V_{6}=\,4tx\,\partial_{x}+4t^{2}\partial_{t}-(x^{2}+2t)\,u\,\partial_{u}$

Can anybody explain in detail, the classification of above Lie algebra into 1- and 2-dimensional optimal sub-algebras based on technique of Patera and co-authors. 
It seems to me that, firstly one have to decompose abstract Lie algebra into some sort of direct sums of sub-algebras but I am not sure.

I have studied following articles as well:

1. Group‐invariant solutions and optimal systems for multidimensional
   hydrodynamics
2. A Note on Optimal Systems for the
   Heat Equation
3. A Technique to Classify the Similarity Solutions
   of Nonlinear Partial (Integro-)Differential Equations.
   II. Full Optimal Subalgebraic Systems

**Additional Example :**

I have asked also this type of question to expert in Lie algebra classification for classification of 1-dimensional Lie algebra using abstract Lie algebra, the question was actually snapshot pdf doc with 8-dimensional Lie algebra which want to classify

[image]

**The expert responded as**

The first thing to do before starting a sub algebra classification is
to identify the Lie algebra that you are considering as an abstract
Lie algebra in a basis independent way. In your case the structure is
very simple

Your algebra L is the direct sum of 4 indecomposable Lie algebras:

```
 L = L_1 + L_2 + L_3 + L_4
```

with

```
L_1 = { V-2-V_1, V_3, V_4} = sl(2,R),  L_2 = {V_6, V_7, V_5} , L_3 }, 

L_3= {V_1+V_2}, L_3 ={{V_8} .
```

The one dimensional algebras {V_1+V_2} and {V_8} form a basis for the
center of L. As a direct sum of  in-decomposable Lie algebras the algebra L has two types of sub-algebras: splitting and non-splitting. Splitting subalgebras are themselves direct sums of subalgebras of the
indecomposable components of L. The non splitting subalgebras are
obtained from the splitting  ones by a procedure called the Goursat
twist. A representative list of nontrivial sub-algebras of sl(2,R) is given by
the two-dimensional algebra

```
 {V_1-V_2, V_3}
```

and three one dimensional sub-algebras

```
 {V_3-V_4} =o(2), {V-2-V__1} = o(1,1)
```

and

```
V_3 ( a nilpotent element in sl(2,R).
```

There are 3 two-dimensional mutually non conjugate sub-algebras of
s_3,1, namely
{V_6,V_5}, {V_6,V_7} and {V_5,V_7}.  Mutually non-conjugate one
dimensional subalgebras are
{V_5},{V_6},{V_7},{V_5+ V_7},{V_5 -V_7}. The last two are conjugate by an
outer automorphism
(like time reversal or space reflection). These can be used if you are
studying an equation invariant under such transformations.

Comment: I have Olver's book, but I probably understand less of it overall than you do. That said, an optimal system according to Olver is essentially a list of the conjugacy classes of subalgebras of the given Lie Algebra. You may find this a helpful overview of the topic of Lie Algebras: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra

Comment: cross-posted to MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/239291/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classification of $6$-dimensional abstract Lie algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ goes as follows. By Levi's theorem we have $L\cong S\ltimes R$, where $R$ denotes the solvable radical of $L$, and $S$ a (semisimple) Levi subalgebra. We have two cases. Either $L$ is solvable, or $L$ is not solvable. In the second case, $S\neq 0$, and
we can use the classification of semisimple Lie algebras of dimension $n\le 6$ for the Levi subalgebras. There are only a few cases to consider for $S\neq 0$, e.g., $S=\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$, or $S=\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})\times \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$. Over $\mathbb{R}$ we also have to consider $\mathfrak{so}_3(\mathbb{R})$ and direct products. Now it is quite easy to classify all non-solvable Lie algebras of dimension $6$. 
For the second case, $L$ is solvable, and we can use a classification of the nilpotent radical $N$ of $R$ to obtain a classification. This is expained [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152952/complete-classification-of-six-dimensional-non-semi-simple-lie-algebra).

Once you have the classification of $6$-dimensional Lie algebras, e.g., the classification by Turkowsky, you can just check about $1$-and $2$-dimensional subalgebras.

Comment: It seems only dimension of Lie algebra matters during classification. But what about different non-zero commutations in all six dimensional algebras ? Wouldn't they effect classification in any way?

Comment: They all effect the classification. For this reason the classification gets much harder each time you increase the dimension. Currently $n=6$ is the limit to have a complete classification of all $n$-dimensional Lie algebras.